# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use JavaScript to assign an action to an HTML form but, I am getting ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in the assignment.

My code:

```
<form action="/" method="POST" name="search-theme-form" id="search-theme-form" >
User <input type="text" name="user" />
Term<input type="text" name="term" />
Subject<input type="text" name="subject" />
Grade<input type="text" name="grade" />
Marks<input type="text" name="marks" />
<script>
var params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
var studentId = params.get("stdid");
var studentId = params.get("stdid");
var x = "app/students/"  + studentId;
document.search-theme-form.action = x;
</script>
    <input id="submitButton"  type="submit"value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: `document.search-theme-form.action = x;` - is invalid in dot notation. Use bracket notation instead if you need to assign to a property with that name

Answer (score 3):

You can not use `dot (.)` operator if the key has `hyphen` in them. Use `bracket notation []` to access the properties.

```
document["search-theme-form"].action = x;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `document.querySelector('[name="search-theme-form"]')` for better approach. Also, always check for the `console` of your browser to check the error and try resolving that. The issue was that you were not selecting the `form` element so using `document.querySelector('[name="search-theme-form"]')` will select the `form` element and then add `action` to it. Thus, `document.search-theme-form.action` was `undefined` at left hand side as you need to use `document['search-theme-form'].action` instead.

```js
var params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
var studentId = params.get("stdid");
var studentId = params.get("stdid");
var x = "app/students/"  + studentId;
document.querySelector('[name="search-theme-form"]').action = x;
```

```html
<form action="/" method="POST" name="search-theme-form" id="search-theme-form" >
User <input type="text" name="user" />
Term<input type="text" name="term" />
Subject<input type="text" name="subject" />
Grade<input type="text" name="grade" />
Marks<input type="text" name="marks" />
```

Comment: Yes, but *why*? What did the error mean? Why does this work instead? (Also: Why not use the `id`?)

Comment: @jainilvachhani glad to help. Also please read the reason for that error.